# How do I can add a package with the latest changes if the release has not been updated?

Tags: yarnpkg

I want to add to your project the next [package](https://github.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider)
But faced with the following problem: in this package has commits that took the author but the release is not updated.

How do I can add a package with the latest changes if the release has not been updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install packages from GitHub directly using the following command:

```
yarn add user/repo
```

This command also works with npm, and will download a package from GitHub and search for a `package.json` in the root directory. If found, it will resolve the package's dependencies and install.

For your specific package, try:

```
yarn add ionden/ion.rangeslider
```

Comment: I tried all the methods described in the documentation and this method does not work (

Comment: @John I tried it before posting and it worked for me. Could you edit the error message into your question, and check your version with `yarn -V`?

Comment: Working! updated yarn. Thank you so much! yarn version: 0.17.10

Comment: @John glad it helped, presumably it was only added recently.